# Bypass Shopify auth when developing Shopify apps locally with Koa & Next JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, koa, shopify-app

So I'm following https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react but ever since I `ngrok`'d it's too slow.

Is there any way I can develop locally? I know Shopify is a hosted solution but `ngrok` makes it way too slow for me.

I'm from India & I think the servers are from US & it's so slow that it takes literally 5 mins & sometimes it doesn't even load properly at all.

Here's my current `server.js`:

```js
require('isomorphic-fetch')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const Koa = require('koa')
const next = require('next')
const { default: createShopifyAuth } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-auth')
const { verifyRequest } = require('@shopify/koa-shopify-auth')
const session = require('koa-session')

dotenv.config()

const { PORT, NODE_ENV, SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY, SHOPIFY_API_KEY } = process.env

const port = parseInt(PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = new Koa()
    server.use(session({ secure: true, sameSite: 'none' }, server))
    server.keys = [SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY]
    server.use(
        createShopifyAuth({
            apiKey: SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
            secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
            scopes: ['read_products'],
            afterAuth(ctx) {
                const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session
                ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, {
                    httpOnly: false,
                    secure: true,
                    sameSite: 'none',
                })
                ctx.redirect('/')
            },
        })
    )

    server.use(verifyRequest())
    server.use(async (ctx) => {
        await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res)
        ctx.respond = false
        ctx.res.statusCode = 200
        return
    })
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

Can I set the `dev` variable somewhere & bypass Shopify auth (Idk much about `koa`) to code my app locally & then check the final result on Shopify app store?

I even tried `serveo`, `lynk`, `sish` & many other `ngrok` alternatives. None of them worked. `serveo` did until it didn't. So I gotta use 8 hours of `ngrok` but any other solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Well your app is actually self sufficient entity, meaning that it doesn't require Shopify in order to work. The only part you need is the Access Token to make request to the Shopify API (you can save that as a static variable for now). Other than that as long as you prevent the default redirections to Shopify, there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to develop your app locally without the need of a ngrok server.

Comment: @drip yes exactly. so i tried changing the code to include `dev` variable but i couldn't figure out what to set. it keeps redirecting. i put some `if..else` statement but cant seem to wrap around `koa`. if u have any ideas, lemme know :)

Comment: Well I'm still stuck with the express approach so I'm not to well versed in koa, but from what I can see there are 2 koa specific shopify packages that seems to handle the redirection and validation logic. For your dev instance you will have to remove them and use the static Access Token. I'm referring to the `createShopifyAuth` and `verifyRequest()` methods, I assume that are responsible for the token and redirection. This is just an observation, I haven't use Koa ( for a full shopify App ) so I can't say nothing for sure.

Comment: well thanks anyways. its currently working fine thanks to Next JS HMR but bootup takes 5-10 mins of time. and if i make changes it takes 4-5 mins to reflect. i'll try your solution if it wastes too much of my time :)